# How to rewrite this Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, t-sql

How it's possible to rewrite this query with the INNER JOIN

```
 INNER JOIN [TD_DAT_DATe] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON DAT_Date 
           BETWEEN [Date Début] AND [Date Fin]**
```

```
SELECT 
         SUBSTRING([Adhésion/Renouvellement],1,1) [Adhésion/Renouvellement],
         [Code Evénement],
         CAST(DAT_Periode+'01' AS DATE) Période,
         COD_CodeProduit CodeProduit,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CAST(IdAdhesion AS VARCHAR)+'-'+CAST(DAT_Date AS VARCHAR)) [Exposition NB Jour]
         --INTO TF_COD_COntratDeclareGarantiePBIexpo
**FROM #ZZ3 WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [TD_DAT_DATe] WITH (NOLOCK)
        ON DAT_Date 
           BETWEEN [Date Début] AND [Date Fin]**
WHERE DAT_Periode >= '202201'  
GROUP BY 
         SUBSTRING([Adhésion/Renouvellement],1,1),
         [Code Evénement],
         CAST(DAT_Periode+'01' AS DATE),
         COD_CodeProduit
```

I try many ways to rewrite the query.

Comment: The query *has* an `INNER JOIN`, so what's the problem..?

Comment: Aside: putting `NOLOCK` everywhere as a matter of course is a [bad habit](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere). You know it's gone too far when you find yourself doing this on a local temporary table. Declaring `VARCHAR` without a length is [another bad habit](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: It is not a good SQL to start with. There are no aliases for the fields. Likely you don't even a need for the inner join.

Comment: the problem is that in the execution plan it brings back more than 7 billion lines :(

Comment: That's an invalid INNER JOIN. You can't INNER JOIN on a BETWEEN condition - that should be part of the WHERE clause. What is the linkage between  `#ZZ3` and `TD_DAT_DATe` (what column connects the two tables)?

Comment: Minor correction - in my previous comment, it should read *You can't INNER JOIN on just a BETWEEN condition*.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that in the execution plan it brings back more than 7 billion lines :(

[image]

Comment: Yes that is because it takes the carthesian product of the tables when the join is not coupled.
The join should be more like :

ON DAT_Date = DAT_Periode AND DAT_Date 
           BETWEEN [Date Début] AND [Date Fin]**

Comment: I meant cartesian product where every row in one set gets joined with every row in the other set.

Comment: This is not an answer, and should not be posted here. Instead, edit your post and add the information to the question where it belongs. The [edit] link is in the lower left, just below the tags. This non-answer should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The join should be more like :

```
ON DAT_Date = DAT_Periode AND DAT_Date BETWEEN [Date Début] AND [Date Fin]
```

Comment: Not quite. The JOIN should be `ON DAT_DATE = DAT_Periode`, and the `BETWEEN` should be moved to the `WHERE` clause.